# consecutive number in loop in c programming language

Tags: c

How I find and print  consecutive two heads and tails through this code,
what should I have to add in this code please help me,
I tried hard and failed please help me
, I could not write code for the consecutive number,
how to count the
number of times when consecutive two head or consecutive tail occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
int flip(); 
int main() 
{ 
    int loop;     
    int headCount = 0;
    int tailCount = 0; 
    srand( time( NULL ) );  
    for ( loop = 1; loop <= 100; loop++ ) { 
        if ( flip() == 0 ) 
        { 
            tailCount++; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            headCount++; 
        }
        if ( loop % 10 == 0 )
        {         
            printf( "\n" ); 
        } 
    } 
    printf( "\nThe total number of consecutive Heads was %d\n", headCount );
    printf( "The total number ofconsecutive Tails was %d\n", tailCount ); 
    return 0; 
}

int flip() 
{ 
    int HorT = rand() %2;
    if ( HorT == 0) { 
        printf( "Tails " ); 
    } 
    else
    { 
        printf( "Heads " );    
    } 
    return HorT; 
}
```

Comment: You'll have to remember what the last flip result was and compare it to the new flip result you get in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rup says, you should remember previous result, compare it with new result, and count if they are same.

```
int main() 
{ 
    int loop;     
    int headCount = 0;
    int tailCount = 0; 
    int prevResult = -1;
    srand( time( NULL ) );  
    for ( loop = 1; loop <= 100; loop++ ) { 
        int result = flip();
        if ( result == prevResult ) /* compare it with new result */
        {
            /* count if they are same */
            if ( result == 0 ) 
            { 
                tailCount++; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                headCount++; 
            }
        }
        prevResult = result; /* remember previous result */
        if ( loop % 10 == 0 )
        {         
            printf( "\n" ); 
        } 
    } 
    printf( "\nThe total number of consecutive Heads was %d\n", headCount );
    printf( "The total number ofconsecutive Tails was %d\n", tailCount ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: But now [it is running](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fg9UuBJ5PH2vfrjV).

Comment: plz slove this all question

Answer (score 0):

Add consecutive counts and reset the "other" count.

```
 int headConsecutive = 0;
 int tailConsecutive = 0;

    ...
    if ( flip() == 0 ) 
    { 
        headCount = 0;  // Clear other count
        tailCount++; 
        if (tailCount > tailConsecutive) {
          tailConsecutive = tailCount;
        } 
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Like above, but for Heads
    }
    ...

printf( "\nThe total number of consecutive Tails was %d\n", tailConsecutive);
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the number of *consecutive* heads (or tails), so if `flip==0` you have to reset `headCount = 0,` and vice versa.

Comment: i have to add code in this code for number of times when consecutive two head or consecutive tail occurs.