# counting consecutive value and printing in c programming

Tags: c

how to count consecutive two heads and tails in  this program please help me, I am really stuck, I tried hard but failed please, write the code for consecutive please, I am very hopeful that StackOverflow can help me

```
     #include <stdio.h>

  #include <stdlib.h>

   #include <time.h>

    int flip();

int main()

{

 int loop;
        
 int headCount = 0;

 int tailCount = 0;

   srand( time( NULL ) );  

    for ( loop = 1; loop <= 100; loop++ ) {

    
  if ( flip() == 0 )
{

 tailCount++;

 }

else

{

headCount++;

 }

 if ( loop % 10 == 0 )

  {        

printf( "\n" );

}

}

  printf( "\nThe total number of consecutive Heads was %d\n", headCount );

 printf( "The total number ofconsecutive Tails was %d\n", tailCount );

 return 0;

}

 int flip() {

   int HorT = rand() %2;

if ( HorT == 0) {

  printf( "Tails " );
  }

   else
{
  
printf( "Heads " );    }

return HorT;
 }
```

Comment: Your classmate has a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642567/consecutive-number-in-loop-in-c-programming-language

Comment: yes we stuck please help us

Comment: Can you format your code so it's readable?

Comment: Please elaborate on what is failing.

Comment: Do you know what it means to have two consecutive heads or tails? What's stopping you from counting such an occurrence?

Comment: You need to remember the previous flip.  If it's the same as the current, increment the appropriate counter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to count 4 consecutive runs of a tail (is that 3, or 4 or 2?), and I'm not going to worry too much about it.  Mostly posting this to point out some stylistic issues with your code.  You can greatly simplify what you're doing with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int flip(void);
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int loop;
        int max = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 100;
        int count[2] = {0, 0};
        int prev = -1;

        srand(time(NULL));
        for( loop = 0; loop < max; loop++ ) {
                int t = flip();
                if( t == prev ) {
                        count[t] += 1;
                }
                if( loop % 10 == 9 || loop == max - 1 ) {
                        putchar('\n');
                }
                prev = t;
        }
        printf( "\nThe total number of consecutive Heads was %d\n", count[0]);
        printf( "The total number of consecutive Tails was %d\n", count[1]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
int
flip(void)
{
        int HorT = rand() % 2;
        fputs(HorT ? "Heads " : "Tails ", stdout);
        return HorT;
}
```